# Access items of a container with a pattern

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++, object-oriented-design, uml

I've two C++ classes with a relation: a container class which has a list of items. For example a library has got many books. The classes are the library and the book.

Now from the external world I have to create, update and delete books. In addition there other classes that are interested to know when an event on a book happens and these (observers) instances can be created at run-time.

Now I've got different ways to proceed:

1) Use always the container to do the operation: central point of management but I have to create couples of methods for example setTitle(bookID) that call setTitle() on the book, bad;

2) Use a getBook() on the container to return a reference of the book, allow the modification, at this point I have to use a commit method to notify the container which can notify the observer but in this way the pattern doesn't force a "commit", I mean if the external caller doesn't call commit() I loose :)

3) Use a getBook() on the container to return a copy of the book and an update method of the container to overwrite the book, central point of management again but the book if big is a problem, a lot of copies are really bad.

Any tips? Is there any pattern that covers this use case?

Comment: You could look into the Composite Pattern which might be what you want. It would allow you to treat a library as if it were a book, but that might not be quite what you're looking for. You could also simply make multiple interfaces for your library or books or whatever and have users only access whichever interface is appropriate for them.

Comment: Using a composite can be difficult in this case because I haven't got a natural "tree structure". I could return a proper interface from the container to the external world but if I apply the oberver pattern to the container I need a way to have a "commit" method or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  If the language were C# or Java, you could use reflection, proxies, or delegates in order to learn whether or not an event occurred in the book class.  Granted, these solutions are a little heavy handed for such a simple matter, however the problem remains.

C++ doesn't have reflection, proxies, or delegates.  However, what you can do is ensure that objects like Book derive from a common class that keeps track of changes.

Specifically, I'm talking about the Subject/Observer pattern.  `Book` would derive from the `Subject` class whose sole methods would be:

```
public:
   bool isChanged() const;
   void resetChanged();

   void addChangeObserver(Observer &observer);
protected:
   void setChanged();
```

The idea is that `Subject` can tell you if an object has changed and its changed status can be reset.  In addition it lets you keep track of observers through `addChangeObserver`.

`Book` would derive from `Subject`, and `Library` would initially reset the change status of all added books.  It would then have a `getBook` method and assuming Book responsibly sets the change status, `Library` could later know it.  If you wish to perform an action *upon* a change event, then it would add itself as an `Observer` for all books added (at which point `Library` would also have to derive from `Observer`).

Again, this is a little overboard, but you gain all the advantages of decoupling at the slight expensive of complicating the code.  However, in a large project, you almost have to do it this way since keeping code decoupled is increasingly important as it grows.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Since the observers can be created at run-time, using the observer patterns on the books is difficult because I have to register the observer on all the books created at the moment. My idea was to use the container to notify the observer that a book is changed.

Comment: @user2944616 You can use this pattern to also be a `Subject` for any `Book` in the `Library` changing.  The `Library` uses the observer pattern for knowing things about the books it holds, but there is no reason why it should stop there.

Comment: Yep maybe you are right. The best option is to use a "double" observer pattern and return from the container the reference